# How can I only display projects inside a treeviewer eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am making a tree viewer in Eclipse which would be used to pick a project and then I would find out the location of the project and zip it up.

I can currently display a tree which shows all the projects but it also allows you to expand the tree.

I am doing this in a wizard so I am unable to any dialogs.

I think I would need a filter but after using Google for a while I was unable to figure out how I could do this.

This is how I am currently making the viewer.

```java
TreeViewer view = new TreeViewer(composite,new WorkbenchLabelProvider(),new BaseWorkbenchContentProvider());
view.setInput(ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's showing you exactly what that content provider is written to show.

The short answer is to setInput(ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProjects()) and use the ArrayContentProvider with a ListViewer rather than the TableViewer.

The long answer is that the content provider you were using returns both the top level elements for the tree control using getElements() and any resource's children via getChildren(), and your case is not interested in the results of getChildren().

Answer (score 0):

Projects are never nested so you only really need a `TableViewer` to show them. You can get the list of projects using:

```java
IProject [] projects = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProjects();
```

The same label provider will work.